# Livewire performing double queries

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm checking the laravel-debugbar and found that the amount of queries is twice as it should be (in my opinion)

Laravel debugbar :
[image: laravel-debugbar]

While it should be called only once when rendering the view,

The Livewire Class :

```
class AllTodos extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $todoId;

    protected $listeners = [
        'todoAdded' => '$refresh',
        'deleteConfirmed' => 'delete',
        'completeConfirmed' => 'complete'
    ];

    public function deleteConfirmation($id)
    {
        $this->todoId = $id;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alertConfirmation', [
            'message' => 'Are you sure want to delete this task ?',
            'action' => 'deleteConfirmed'
        ]);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $todo = Todo::findOrFail($this->todoId);
        $todo->delete();

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alertInfo', [
            'message' => 'Todo has been deleted.',
            'icon' => 'success'
        ]);
    }

    public function completeConfirmation($id)
    {
        $this->todoId = $id;

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alertConfirmation', [
            'message' => 'Are you sure want to complete this task ?',
            'action' => 'completeConfirmed'
        ]);
    }

    public function complete()
    {
        $todo = Todo::findOrFail($this->todoId);
        $todo->update([
            'is_completed' => 1
        ]);

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alertInfo', [
            'message' => 'Todo has been completed.',
            'icon' => 'success'
        ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.all-todos', [
            'todos' => Todo::latest()->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }
}
```

The view :

```
<div>
    <livewire:add-todo />
    <table class="w-full m-4">
        <thead class="text-md font-semibold tracking-wide text-left text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 uppercase border-b border-gray-600">
            <th class="px-4 py-3">Title</th>
            <th class="px-4 py-3">Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-white">
            @foreach($todos as $todo)
                <tr class="text-gray-700">
                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">{{ $todo->title }}</td>
                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">
                        <button class="p-2 pl-5 pr-5 transition-colors duration-700 transform bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-gray-100 text-lg rounded-lg focus:border-4 border-indigo-300" wire:click.prevent="completeConfirmation({{ $todo->id }})">Complete</button>
                        <button class="p-2 pl-5 pr-5 transition-colors duration-700 transform bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-400 text-gray-100 text-lg rounded-lg focus:border-4 border-red-300" wire:click="deleteConfirmation({{ $todo->id }})">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach    
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="m-4">
        {{ $todos->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

The layouts :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @livewireStyles
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container mx-auto p-6 font-mono">
        <div class="w-full mb-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
                <livewire:all-todos />
            </div>
        </div>            
    </section>

    <x-alerts />

    <script src="{{ asset('js/swal.js') }}"></script>
    
    @stack('js')

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use mount special method, its resulting this same double queries,
How to reduce these amount of queries ?

Comment: That doesn't look normal, looks like it's rendering twice. How do you render this component?

Comment: @Qirel thats on my AllTodos Class, i render it on built in livewire render() function by using eloquent  Todo::latest()->paginate(5), and pass it to blade view, thats it, thats why i'm wondering what did went wrong

Comment: No, I mean, how do you render the entire component? Is it a full-page component, is it rendered from another component?

Comment: @Qirel no, i use full page component, and pass it directly to route --> Route::get('/', AllTodos::class), and render it to app.layout, please see my updated question

Comment: But you have it as a full page component, that renders it, and then in the layout, you add it manually add well? So it renders twice. But since you have no slot, it only renders visually once - but the component is called twice, once from the route and once from `<livewire:all-todos />`. If you replace that line with `{{ $slot}}`, it should work and only call the component once

Comment: @Qirel thats it man, thank you so much ! i thought it was the same whether to use <livewire:all-todos /> or {{ $slot }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in the comments, the issue here is that you don't have a [slot](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots) in your layout - which is where the full-page Livewire component is injected. Instead, you render the component directly in your layout using `<livewire:all-todos />`.

This means two things,

1. Your component is called twice (but only rendered once, since there is no slot for the full-page component, but the in-line rendering works as expected)
2. Your `all-todos` component will be rendered on *all* your pages that uses that layout.

This first point here, is why you are getting double queries.

##### The solution

To solve your issue, you simply have to replace the inline rendering of the compoinent which is `<livewire:all-todos />` with the magic variable `{{ $slot }}`.

```html
<section class="container mx-auto p-6 font-mono">
    <div class="w-full mb-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
    </div>            
</section>
```

##### Related reading material,

- [Laravel on Slots in Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots)
- [Rendering full-page components in Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components)